# Android APK - How do applications connect to their servers without DNS queries

Tags: android, dns, apk, reverse-engineering

I wanted to understand how the applications on play store (majority of them) connect to their servers without performing explicit DNS queries. I downloaded the APK file and reverse-engineered the code and I could not find any IPs. May be the IPs are hidden in the code through some obfuscation, like .so files etc. But what is not clear to me is that, these IPs are perennial and never ending, so the possibility of hard coding is very less, because each day I try to launch the same version of the application using the same phone and then collect the .pcap files I see that the application is talking to different servers. I understand that it could be over some kind of cloud servers, where the IPs in the subnet range would be huge, but again, the IPs are from different cloud servers.

So how does the application learn about these new IPs everyday without a software update?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The domain name's IP address may be cached locally after the first lookup.

The DNS cache is flushed on device reboot. However, the application you're analyzing may start up as soon as the device boots, making it difficult for you to monitor network traffic for DNS lookups.

I suggest configuring the connection to use a DNS server you control and can monitor. It may be easier to just remove the DNS server such that lookups fail and are never cached. This way when you run the app, you should see the lookups.

You should do a reverse DNS lookup of the IP addresses to see what domains are associated with them and then grep the code and application resources for those domains.

If the previous suggestions don't help, I would also suggest searching for network related API calls and analyzing the code around that area for literals that contain host names.

It's also possible that the application uses a one or more hard-coded IP addresses to get additional addresses. This would explain why the list of IP addresses always seems to change.

Comment: Your guess was partially correct. My new observation was that, after the DNS query, the application used to send out a request to the IP he learns in the DNS to further get a list of server IPs and VPN server IPs which he actually caches. I was able to only reproduce this issue when I unistalled the app and reinstalled it and tried to login. But once he logs in and logs out, and then re-logs in (even after couple of days), he uses the cache to send requests, but never performs a DNS. In essence I was able to see the DNS requests only on the first login.